# How to sort months as they should be sorted?

Tags: javascript, canvas

I'm having a chart build in javascript html5 canvas and I'm trying to sort the data month by month, but when I enter them, they are sorted alphabetical instead the correct month order.

```
class RaceChart {
  constructor(canvas_id, data) {
    this.canvas = document.getElementById(canvas_id);
    this.data = data;

    this.first_time = true;
    this.date = null;
    this.date_data = null;
    this.id_to_left_text = {};
    this.id_to_left_image = {};
    this.id_to_center_text = {};
    this.id_to_center_image = {};
    this.id_to_bar_colors = {};
    this.value_anims = {};
    this.y_anims = {};
    this.label_anims = {};

    this.ctx = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
    request_animation_loop(() => this.draw());
  }

  show(date) {
    this.date = date;
    this.date_data = this.data.filter(row => row.date === date);
    this.date_data.sort((a, b) => b.value - a.value);
    for (let row of this.date_data) {
      this.id_to_bar_colors[row.id] = row.bar_color;
      this.id_to_left_image[row.id] = row._left_image;
      this.id_to_left_text[row.id] = row.left_text;
      this.id_to_center_image[row.id] = row._center_image;
      this.id_to_center_text[row.id] = row.center_text;
    }
  }
```

Comment: This isn't a [mcve], so it's hard to say, but `this.date_data.sort((a, b) => b.value - a.value);` should probably be something like `this.date_data.sort((a, b) => b.month - a.month);`, assuming `month` is a sortable month number, or has a sortable month name (not plain string comparisons between, say, "January" and "December").

Answer (score 1):

Add another parameter which is just pure numbers, 0-11. assign each object a number based on its text month value. Then sort on those numbers